# What is exactly meant by this infimum notation?

Tags: probability, supremum-and-infimum

I read about what an infimum is and it makes sense, but there is something about this notation that is confusing to me.

It is from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00263.pdf)

> Recall that in regression, the forecaster $H$ outputs at each step $t$ a CDF $F_t$ targeting $y_t$. We will use $F_t^{-1}:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ to denote the quantile function $F_t^{-1}(p) = \inf\{y: p \le F_t(y)\}$

If $y$ is the value of the CDF, shouldn't the quantile function be the supremum y value that is less than or equal to $F_t(y)$?

Comment: yes I do, can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $F_t$ is a CDF, it is an increasing function. That means that larger $y$ gives larger $F_t(y)$. Optimally, we want $F^{-1}_t(p)$ to be the *smallest* $y$ such that $F_t(y)=p$. So that's what it's defined to be. All the other notation is just there to make sure that the value actually exists and is well-defined. If $F_t$ is known to be continuous, it is unnecessary, but if $F_t$ is allowed to be discontinuous, all that extra stuff is necessary.

By the increasing nature of $F_t$, we may as well look for the smallest $y$ such that $F_t(y)\geq p$, except that $y$-values such that $F_t(y)\geq p$ are certain to exist. Then we pick out the smallest such $y$, except there might not *be* a smallest, so we take the $\inf$ instead.